# Proving $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed by analytic approach.

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials

I want to prove that $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed in the following way. Let us first take a non-constant polynomial $F$ with coefficients from $\Bbb R.$  Then $F \in \Bbb R[X] \subset \Bbb C[X].$ Now consider the polynomial function $$F : \Bbb C \longrightarrow \Bbb C$$ defined by $z \mapsto F(z).$ If I can prove that $F$ is both open as well as closed in $\Bbb C$ then we are through. Because then $F(\Bbb C) = \Bbb C$ (since $\Bbb C$ is both open and closed in $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C$ is connected so either $F(\Bbb C) = \varnothing\ \text {or}\ \Bbb C.$ But since $F$ is a polynomial $F(\Bbb C) \neq \varnothing$). But then $\exists$ $z \in \Bbb C$ such that $F(z)=0$ i.e. $z$ is a root of $F$ in $\Bbb C.$ Which proves $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed.

I have proved that $F$ is a closed map on $\Bbb C$ when $\Bbb C$ is endowed with the usual metric topology. How do I prove that $F$ is an open map in order to prove the required result?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)), which states that every analytic non-constant map from an open connected subset of $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ is open.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't know the proof of it. Can you prove it in your answer?

Comment: No, I cannot. But you will find it on any Complex Analysis textbook. Consider, for instance, Reinhold Remmert's *Theory of Complex Functions*. It is there, on section 5 from chapter 8.

Comment: Thanks. Is the proof based on identity theorem?

Comment: The OMT follows from  Rouche's theorem in a straightforward way...

Comment: Indeed. And I have just noted that the Wikipedia article that I have provided a link to contains that proof.